# POWERSHELL Miss small thing

Tags: powershell

Just wondering what I miss here

```
Get-WindowsFeature | where {{($_.Installed -eq "$True") -and ($_.FeatureType -eq "$Role")}} | Format-List name,i
nstalled,featuretype
```

I am receiving the opposite result ,  `False + true + Feature + Role`  ..

Comment: what output do you expect? What is $Role?

Comment: I expect to get "Featuretype" $role  there are 3 type of "Featuretype : Feature, role, role service

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two curly brackets within your `Where-Object`cmdlet, one is enough. I don't see `$Role` defined but after your comment, I suppose its a string array and look like this: `$Role = @('Feature', 'role', 'role service')`.

You have to use the `-In` parameter to check, whether the `FeatureType` is one of the types defined in `$Role`, not `-eq`. Also, you can omit the quotes on the `$true` check:

```
Get-WindowsFeature | 
    Where { $_.Installed -eq $true -and $_.FeatureType -In $Role } |
    Select Installed, FeatureType
```

Comment: You not only *can* but *should* omit the quotes - don't compare apples and oranges

Comment: Hi Again ,First of all thanks for comment , If i delete the curly brackets  it not working , it is automatically output empty output . i have tried your script as well and it is not working ** Unexpected token 'In' **

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen , once i omit the quotes  i get empty output  ( nothing not happens  ) : PS P:\> Get-WindowsFeature | where {($_.Installed -eq $True) -and ($_.FeatureType -eq $Role)} | Format-List name,feature
type,installed

Comment: Just to clarified  my question guys  , the idea started once i run thing syntax "Get-WindowsFeature | where {$_.installed -eq $true}" now i just now to get another value " FeatureType "

Comment: Hi There ,  I managed with  it !   " Get-WindowsFeature | where-object {$_.FeatureType -eq "Role" -and $_.Installed -eq "True"}" working

Comment: Are you using PowerShell 2.0? Which version of Windows are you on?